# Kindle 2 not detected 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, kindle

My kindle is not being mounted by the machine. I am using a kindle touch 2 on 12.04 LTS. Any suggestions. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What changes in **`lsusb`**, before and after you attach the device?

Comment: What is the Kindle hardware model, and software release?

Comment: I have had no issues, under Ubuntu **12.04** or **13.04**, but I skipped from older *Kindle 3* to the *Kindle PaperWhite*.

Answer (score 1):

this device uses mtp , this command should help :

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

other people got it to work with calibre:

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

try both and tell us what worked :) would be good to know 100%

Comment: I've done those two steps prior. It still doesnt seem to pick it up